# How to use ngx-translate in electron part of angular+electron app?

Tags: angular, electron, ngx-translate

I have an Angular (Ionic) app with a desktop version running via Electron.

I'm using ngx-translate in the Angular app without any problem.

I have a few localized strings in the Electron app especially the window top menu.

What is the best practice to translate the Electron part using the same asset file of the Angular part?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem a few months ago, and it doesn't have a perfect solution.

My approach was to send the current language information using `Inter-Process Communication (IPC)` ([documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)).

Simple example of how `ipc` part seems:

`Electron`

```
let settings:{language:string, electronZoom:number};
ipcMain.on("update-settings", function (event, webSettings) {
  settings = webSettings;
});
```

`Web`

```js
// IpcService
  send(channel: string, ...args: any[]): void {
    window.ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args);
  }

// ElectronConnectionService
  updateSettings(settings: Settings){
    if(!this.isElectronPlatform) {return;}
    this.ipcSvc.send('update-settings', settings);
  }
```

Once you have got language throw ipc, to handle multi-language in electron part, the library `i18next` may help ([documentation](https://github.com/i18next/i18next)).

Comment: I have already an IPC to communicate between web part and electron part but your answer only explains how to pass the language selection. Once I'm in Electron typescript code and I know the language, how do I load the json asset and get the localized strings?

Comment: Hello! I edited my answer. But basically, take a look [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next) library. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But it's horrible!!! :-( I don't want to have to use another library. I have customed a little bit ngx-translate, I don't wan to have to do the same with another lib. Perhaps the "simpler" is to pass the localized string via IPC. I have opened a Github issue: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1408